# JAXB, how to unmarshall different object in the case of error

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stream, jaxb

Does JAXB provide some API to unmarshall the XML stream to an alternative object depending of the root element?

The application which produces the stream may return either

```
<Result>
 <data>...</data>
</Result>
```

or

```
<Error>
  <cause>...</cause>
</Error>
```

Depending of the status of execution. In both cases the output is read from stdin, and I need to unmarshall either Result object or Error object depending of the output. Is this possible with JAXB, without storing the output in a temporary String and checking the content manually, and deciding which object to parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use multiple classes and add `@XmlRootElement` annotations with names accordingly, then create a `JAXBContext` by specifying both classes.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
static class Result {
    String data;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Error")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
static class Error {
    String cause;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Result.class, Error.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    String sampleErrorInput = "<Error><cause>Sample cause</cause></Error>";
    String sampleResultInput = "<Result><data>Sample data</data></Result>";
    for (String input : Arrays.asList(sampleErrorInput, sampleResultInput)) {
        Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(input));
        if (obj instanceof Error) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ((Error) obj).cause);
        } else if (obj instanceof Result) {
            System.out.println("Result: " + ((Result) obj).data);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above produces this output:

```
Error: Sample cause
Result: Sample data
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is a software framework that allows Java developers to map Java classes to XML representations, that's all. You should take care to return the correct xml structure depending of the result of your execution, and you can return `Result` element or `Error` element, or anything else.